# missing a tick label that has been named

Tags: pgfplots, axis, ticks

So I made this graph, and this graph can't show me the tick `$\frac{5}{2}\pi$` at `7.85`.

I've tried to enlarge the `x` max range, give extra ticks (and extra tick label) but nothing works. Anyone can help me? Thanks!

```
\documentclass[10pt,openany,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{a4wide}
\usepackage{amsfonts,amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.13}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,angles,positioning,intersections,quotes,decorations.markings}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis} [
        axis line style = thick,
        axis x line = middle,
        axis y line = middle,
        xtick = {-3.14, -1.57, 0., ..., 7.85, 9.42},
        ytick = {-1, 0, 1},
        xlabel = {$\theta$},
        ylabel = {$y$},
        xticklabels = {$-\pi$, $-\frac{\pi}{2}$, , $\frac{\pi}{2}$, $\pi$, $\frac{3\pi}{2}$, $2\pi$, $\frac{5\pi}{2}$, $3\pi$},
        xmin = -3.5, xmax = 10,
        ymin = -1.5, ymax = 1.5,
        font = \tiny,
    ]

    \addplot[black, thin, samples = 1000, smooth, domain=-3.14:0] {cos(deg(x))};
    \addplot[cyan, thin, samples = 1000, smooth, domain=0:3.140000] {cos(deg(x))};
    \addplot[black, thin, samples = 1000, smooth, domain=3.14:8.5] {cos(deg(x))};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Your code generates errors. Please post a working example.

Comment: Replacing your `xtick={...}` with `xtick={-3.14,-1.57,...,9.42}` works for me (which avoids the rounding errors).

Comment: @StefanPinnow It worked too on me! Thank you so much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By lucky chance, you could get your desired list of ticks if you'd remove some of the intermediate values and use `xtick = {-3.14, -1.57, ..., 9.42}`.

Why does this work? The above list will be expanded to

```
-3.14 
-1.57 
-0.00002 
1.56998 
3.13997 
4.70996 
6.27995 
7.84995 
9.41994
```

As you can see, the floating point precision of pgf is not that good. By pure luck, the last tikz is calculated to be `9.41994`, which is lower than the upper boundary set to `9.42`.

The list from your question, `xtick = {-3.14, -1.57, 0., ..., 7.851, 9.42}`, evaluates to

```
-3.14 
-1.57
0.
1.57 
3.14001 
4.71002 
6.28003 
9.42
```

Notice the absence of a value around `7.85`. This tick is missing because pgf would calculate the next step in the list to be `7.85004`, which is above the upper limit of `7.85`.

You could avoid the problem by leaving a bit of margin for rounding errors with `xtick = {-3.14, -1.57, 0., ..., 7.851, 9.42}`.

Comment: @samcarter, although it should be clear what to do in case one would _not be lucky_ with the end of the given `xtick` range, maybe you should just add that it would be enough the increase the last number a bit, e.g. in this case to `9.43` to also make the last tick (+ label) visible/show up.

Comment: @StefanPinnow Isn't that already covered in "You could avoid the problem by leaving a bit of margin for rounding errors with xtick = {-3.14, -1.57, 0., ..., 7.851, 9.42}."?

Comment: thanks for your explanation!

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz, in principle yes, but then I would apply that suggestion/advice as well to the "final" solution. That is I would use/show instead of `9.42` minimum `9.43`. Maybe also simply `9.5` or `10`. The only requirement would be to be smaller than "the next step". I'd do that, because _maybe_ (I didn't check) you get the shown evaluated tick values by TeXing with pdfLaTeX, but would yield something larger than 9.42 when TeXing with e.g. LuaLaTeX.

Comment: Of course your solution is fine as is. My suggestion would just make it a bit more "general".

Comment: @StefanPinnow I don't consider the second part a "final solution", I just wanted to mention that it was just pure luck that it worked because it was mentioned in comments.

Comment: I agree with the "luck". Ok, then "we'll" leave it as is and in doubt hopefully someone reads our comments ;) +1 for the great answer.